# In Perl, how can I print the key corresponding to the maximum value in a hash?

Tags: perl, hash

How can I print only the first key and element of my hash?

I have already a sorted hash, but I want  to print only the first key and respective value
thanks,

Thanks to all of you at the end I push the keys and the values to  two different @array and print element 0 of each array and it works :)

Comment: What is the first key for you?

Comment: You might find [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Tie-IxHash-1.22/lib/Tie/IxHash.pm) useful if you want a hash that preserves the order of added keys.

Answer (score 8):

Hashes have unordered keys. So, there is no such key as a *first key* in a hash.

However, if you need the key that sorts first (for maximum key value):

```
my %hash = (
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'qux' => 'baz',
);

my ($key) = sort { $b cmp $a } keys %hash;
print "$key => $hash{$key}";  # Outputs: qux => baz
```

Remember to use `<=>` instead of `cmp` for numerical sorting.

Comment: but if I have sort the hash  and I need to print only the first key and value it is not possible?

Answer (score 5):

In perl hashes there is no ordering for keys. Use [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function to get the keys in the order that you want or you can push the keys into an array as you create the hash and your first key will be in zero th index in the array

You can use the below code, i am assuming hash name is my_hash and keys and values are numbers. If you have strings, you can use `cmp` instead of `<=>`. Refer to the sort documentation for more details

**Get the max key**

```
foreach (sort {$b <=> $a} keys %my_hash) {
    print "Keys is $_\n";
    print "Value is $my_hash{$_}\n";
    last;
}
```

**Get the key corresponding to the max value**

```
foreach (sort {$my_hash{$b} <=> $my_hash{$a}} keys %my_hash) {
    print "Keys is $_\n";
    print "Value is $my_hash{$_}\n";
    last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Alan wrote - hashes don't have specific order, but you can sort hash keys:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys(%hash)) {
   print $key . ': ' . $hash{$key} . "\n";
}
```

or, as you wish, get first element from keys array:

```
my @keys = keys(%hash);
print $keys[0];
```

Comment: yes I have already sorted but I want to print only the max value

Comment: @user1051414 Ah, so you need the max value. This is still not clear, do you want max key or max value or max value for a specific key (if the value is an array). Update your question with this information

Comment: yes that print me the key , but I want the key and value, sorry

Comment: @user1051414 if key is $_ then value will be $my_hash{$_}

Comment: Thanks to all of you  at the end I push the keys and the values to a two different @array and print element 0 of each array and it works :)

Comment: You should use `warnings` and use `$keys[0];` instead of `@keys[0];` to access the first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach my $key (sort keys(%hash)) { 
   print "$key" .  "$hash{$key}" . "\n"; 
   last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For large hashes, if you do not need the sorted keys for any other reason, it might be better to avoid sorting.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %hash = map { $_ => rand(10_000) } 'aa' .. 'zz';

my ($argmax, $max) = each %hash;
keys %hash; # reset iterator

while (my ($k, $v) = each %hash) {
    if ($v >= $max) {
        $max = $v;
        $argmax = $k;
    }
}

print "$argmax => $max\n";
```

If you are intent on sorting, you only need the key with the maximum value, not the entire arrays of `keys` and `values`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %hash = map { $_ => rand(10_000) } 'aa' .. 'zz';
my ($argmax) = sort { $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a} } keys %hash;

print "$argmax => $hash{$argmax}\n";
```