# Is there a Perl module for for remembering the order of keys in a hash?

Tags: perl

Is there a "canonical" (pure-)perl implementation of a tree-based ordered key-value storage with O(log(n)) access time?

I've tried searching for "tree" on CPAN but haven't got much insight from that.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164801/in-perl-how-can-i-print-the-key-corresponding-to-the-maximum-value-in-a-hash) inspired me to post my own.

EDIT: So the question was unclearly stated.

What I'm looking for is a storage that barely does what a %hash would do, but maintains the order of its keys at a price of worse algorithmic complexity. All structures with such properties I know so far are based on some kind of tree (B-tree, red-black tree etc), hence the title.

Here's a pseudocode example of what I'd like to see:

```
my $set = Some::Module->new();
$set->store( foo=>1 );
$set->store( bar=>2 );
$set->fetch( "foo" ); # 1
$set->keys(); # bar, foo and not foo, bar
$set->keysBetween( undef, "baz" ); # bar only
```

Comment: Really?  Because if you search for "tree" under CPAN--or if you google for cpan tree, you'll get the Tree module:  http://search.cpan.org/~rkinyon/Tree-1.01/lib/Tree.pm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Tie::IxHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aIxHash) is the [`perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-make-my-hash-remember-the-order-I-put-elements-into-it%3f) recommendation:

```
use Tie::IxHash;
tie my %myhash, 'Tie::IxHash';

for ( my $i=0; $i<20; $i++ ) {

    $myhash{$i} = 2*$i;
}

my @keys = keys %myhash;
# @keys = (0,1,2,3,...)
```

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> This Perl module implements Perl hashes that preserve the order in
>   which the hash elements were added. The order is not affected when
>   values corresponding to existing keys in the `IxHash` are changed. The
>   elements can also be set to any arbitrary supplied order. The familiar
>   perl array operations can also be performed on the IxHash.

Also try searching for "tie hash order" on CPAN if this module doesn't cut the mustard.

Answer (score 2):

see [`Tree`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tree).